# Missing files when using github fork feature

Tags: git, github

I forked repository: 
`https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app` to 
`https://github.com/knagode/shopify_app`

I see that my repo does not contain all the files.

E.g. on original repo inside lib folder (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/tree/master/lib)
There is `shopify_app/middleware` folder.

https://github.com/knagode/shopify_app/tree/master/lib
This same directory is missing in forked repository.

Why is that so?

Comment: The fork seems to be out of date. There are less commits in the fork.

Comment: +1 to @dan1st. "[This branch is 512 commits behind Shopify:master.](https://github.com/knagode/shopify_app/tree/master/lib/shopify_app)". I haven't looked into the git log of the repository, but perhaps the `middleware` directory was added in one of those 512 commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forked repository is 512 commits behind the original repository.

In commit [0480a218ab5e6e12b890669fd02d2263)](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/commit/c57ef409384140e269241854735a337b96ee7d8d#diff-0480a218ab5e6e12b890669fd02d2263), the directory/file you are missing has been added.

This commit was created 2 months ago but the forked repository hasn't been updated since 2017
(The latest commit is [13ef3c4af94532c429b5c12dbd0763e2ae4f36a0](https://github.com/knagode/shopify_app/commit/13ef3c4af94532c429b5c12dbd0763e2ae4f36a0)).

Comment: You are right. Apparently I forked a little while ago and didn't notice the warning. Thanks!